# LocalDB SQL-server version in VS2022

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2022, localdb

Our current Azure build agents are using a `windows-2019` VM-image and that includes VS2019 and SQL LocalDb 2016.

We're wanting to use a more recent version of SQL LocalDb and I'm trying to find out which version of SQL Localdb ships with VS 2022.

Nothing is mentioned in the [Azure hosted agents page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) or related included software [link](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md) for `windows-latest`/`windows-2022`.

Comment: My local VS 2022 installer presents "SQL Server 2019 Express LocalDB" as the installation feature. Of course this doesn't say much about what MS puts on their own images, because while the VS installer may include LocalDB as a feature, it isn't tied to any particular version of LocalDB.

Comment: Why not just download LocalDB separately, either here https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=866658 or here https://info.microsoft.com/ww-landing-sql-server-2022.html?lcid=EN-GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT @@Version` from a `windows-latest` image returns:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU12) (KB5004524) - 15.0.4153.1 (X64)
> Jul 19 2021 15:37:34
> Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 20348: ) (Hypervisor)